# Not able to open and load pickle file in python 3.6.1

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to open and load pickle file but by two ways. But every time I am getting an error.

Request you to please help.

**First way :**

```
enron_data = pickle.load(open("D:/New/ud120-projects/final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "r"))

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Second Way :**

```
enron_data = pickle.load(open("D:/New/ud120-projects/final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "rb"))

Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted
```

Request you to please help

Comment: Could this be related to your error? https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/issues/46

Comment: My guess is that the pickle file is written by a different version of Python interpreter, causing such compatibility issues.

Comment: Did you use `"wb"` mode when originally writing the pickle file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you have to use a raw string and backslashes like this:

```
r'D:\path\to\your\file'
```